# SQL string returns no values when coded in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Using visual studio 2012 express to create a web api that connects to a sql database and searches for a term, and returns values. 
When I run the code, the sql string works. I can copy the string and load it into a query in SQL server 2014 and expected results are returned. 
However, when I run the code here my sql string - on the return data - all my values are null.

Does anyone perhaps have any suggestions

Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPi
{
public class TableBusinessTerm : TableGenericBase<stBusinessTerm>
{
    private string TableName = "[MetadataRepository].[dbo].[QrySocialGraphMobile]";
    public override void CreateTable()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public stBusinessTerm GetBusinessTerm(string termName)
    {
        string sql = "Select * From " + TableName + " Where BusinessTerm = '" + termName + "'";
        var data = new stBusinessTerm();
        bool result = GetRecord(ref data, sql);
        return data;
    }
    protected override void DatabaseRow_Get(DataRow dr, ref stBusinessTerm data)
    {
        DatabaseUtilities.DataRow_Get(dr, "BusinessTerm", ref data.BusinessTerm);
        DatabaseUtilities.DataRow_Get(dr, "BusinessTermLongDesc", ref data.BusinessTermLongDesc);
        DatabaseUtilities.DataRow_Get(dr, "DomainCatID", ref data.DomainCatID);
        DatabaseUtilities.DataRow_Get(dr, "SystemName", ref data.SystemName);
        DatabaseUtilities.DataRow_Get(dr, "DataSteward", ref data.DataSteward);
        DatabaseUtilities.DataRow_Get(dr, "DomainCatName", ref data.DomainCatName);
        DatabaseUtilities.DataRow_Get(dr, "GoldenSource", ref data.GoldenSource);
        DatabaseUtilities.DataRow_Get(dr, "GTS_table", ref data.GTS_table);
        DatabaseUtilities.DataRow_Get(dr, "TableOwnerName", ref data.TableOwnerName);
        DatabaseUtilities.DataRow_Get(dr, "Synonym", ref data.Synonym);
    }

    protected override void DatabaseRow_Get(long autoIncrementedID, ref stBusinessTerm data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void DatabaseRow_Set(ref DataRow dr, stBusinessTerm data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why using ref???

Comment: because I am not totally sure what I am doing truthfully and it was the only way I could avoid s sytnax error. Assume that you are referring to the line `bool result = GetRecord(ref data, sql);
            return data`

Comment: Firstly: **never** concatenate inputs (`termName`) to create SQL - that's **really really dangerous** - you should look at *parameters*. However, the more relevant thing here is that you seem to be using some custom code that you *aren't showing us*. We can't tell what the problem is if we can't see what `GetRecord` does or what `DatabaseRow_Get` does. Right now, it would just throw `NotImplementedExceptions`. What even is `stBusinessTerm`? What is the relationship between `GetRecord` and `DatabaseRow_Get`? because right now: nothing calls that, and `GetRecord` doesn't exist

Comment: it's unneeded complexity. why not use a sqldataadapter ?

Comment: Ok, maybe more details needed. The `TERMNAME` is being passed from a Web page. This then creates the `string sql` which is why I have concatenated the inputs. I have never used sqlDataAdapter, so thought it would be easier to create the sql string and then pass the values to the data rows - clearly this is not the case. Was hoping it was something silly like I had left of a comma, or something, but now see its more complex than that. Thanks for the advise thus far

Comment: @Doruk `SqlDataAdapter` is designed to work with `DataTable`, unless I've missed something - which isn't the scenario here. Also, it would probably be a terrible idea to use `DataTable` or `SqlDataAdapter` here (...or in fact most places...)

Comment: @Jext ultimately, we can't debug this for you, since your `GetBusinessTerm` calls `GetRecord`, which *we can't see*. We have no clue what happens past that point. Plus we can only *guess* at what `stBusinessTerm` looks like. Oh, and we can't see `DatabaseUtilities.DataRow_Get`, although I can probably guess at what that does (`val = (T)dr[columnName]` or some variant of that, with `<T>(... ref T val)`

Answer (score 2):

Your current data code is ... complex and hard to understand, and with much of it missing it is very hard to comment directly on what is happening. However! I strongly suspect you are making life **very** hard for yourself unnecessarily. It *looks* like you have a type `stBusinessTerm` (I'm guessing a `struct`, although that is almost certainly a bad choice here, but that is a separate issue - also: you should generally avoid prefixes like `st` for things), with public fields (another bad choice, almost certainly) that exactly match the column names. In that case, I strongly suggest using a tool such as [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/). Here's the entire code for that, correctly parameterized:

```
public stBusinessTerm GetBusinessTerm(string termName)
{
    using(var conn = GetConnectionFromSomewhere())
    {
        return conn.QuerySingleOrDefault<stBusinessTerm>(@"
Select * From [MetadataRepository].[dbo].[QrySocialGraphMobile]
Where BusinessTerm = @termName",
            new { termName }); // parameters
    }
}
```

and... that's it! Basically, Dapper works on the principle that most of the code that people write to execute commands and consume the results is rote, boring, and usually inefficient and buggy - and it would be better if a library just did all that stuff *for you*.